# Understanding what is wrong in this git commit graph

Tags: git, git-commit

I am trying to figure out what I did wrong looking at my commit graph here. I have used alphabets A and B to show each commits parent. Shouldn't it be going straight instead of bending at `security`

How do you read this kind of a graph to figure out what went wrong? I have been given to believe that a healthy commit graph goes straight all the way. In that case this is not right or is it?

Apologies if the question doesn't have enough information. I don't know how to provide more. Here is the Gitk view

[image: GITK output]

**Edit**

Here is the sourcetree view
[image: SourceTree ouput]

The graph in SourceTree seems to be more healthier as compared to what I see in Gitk. Why are they different?

Comment: To help people understanding the situation, can you post the github network graph (Graphs/Network) or the result of `tig` or `sourcetree` ?

Comment: This is from a TFS git instance. I'm not sure it has graphs/network. What you see is th GitK output. I will add the sourcetree output

Comment: what is odd to me here is that SourceTree seems to show a more healthier graph as compared to what I see in GitK. Why are they different?

Answer (score 2):

Those are identical graphs.  Gitk puts that bend in there to help preserve (very limited) UI space.

Try running:

```
gitk --date-order
```

That should make things look more similar, though it will probably still have a bend at "security".